# Telling a teammate to press forward alone towards the goal

Tags: word-usage, informal-language

Let's say you are playing football and such a situation happened:

After the corner, you had the ball and you gave the pass to the partner ahead, and he alone, what would you say? Would you say?: ***go yourself! or go alone!*** or it is incorrect? or maybe something else?

Comment: I think a native speaker might say "Go for it!" or "Have a go, Boyep!".  In a footballing context they would be understood to mean the player should have an attempt such as a shot at goal themselves or try pressing forwards in an attack (by themselves).  Similarly people might shout "Take a shot!" if they literally mean to take a shot at goal.  I can't think of any phrases that are used as an exclamation in football that specifically use the words "yourself", "solo", "alone", etc.

Comment: You might just shout “yours!” as you pass the ball as a way of telling them it’s their moment and you don’t expect to share in it with them. That’s just a memory from *many* years ago in the school playground though - I don’t know if it’s in common use elsewhere...